# Trouble with looping function into structure index

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct

I'm relatively new to matlab and would really appreciate any help.

Currently, I have a function (we'll call it readf) that reads in data from a single ascii file into a struct of multiple fields (we'll call it cdata).

```
names = cellstr(char('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'));
cdata = readf('filestring','dataNames',names);
```

The function works fine and gives me the correct output of a struct with these field names, with the value of each field name being a cell array of the corresponding data.

My task is to create a for loop that uses this readf function to read in a folder of these ascii files at once. I'm trying to work it so that the for loop creates a struct with an index of the different cdata structs. After trying a few different methods, I am stumped.

This is what I have so far.

```
files = struct2cell(dir('folderstring'));       %creates a cell array of the names of the files withing the folder

for ii=length(files);
    cdata(ii) = readf([folderstring,files(1,1:ii),names],'dataName',names);

end;
```

This is currently giving me the following error.

```
"Error using horzcat 
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."
```

I am not sure what is wrong. How can I fix this code so i can read in all the data from a folder at once??? Is there a better and more efficient way to do this than making an index to this struct? Perhaps a cell array of different structures or even a structure of nested structures? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for ii=length(files);
    cdata(ii) = readf([folderstring,files(1,1:ii),names],'dataName',names);

end;

To:

for ii=1:length(files); % CHECK to make sure length(files) is giving you the right number
    cdata(ii) = readf([folderstring,files{ii},names],'dataName',names);

end;
% CHECK files{ii}, with 1,2,3 etc. is giving you the correct file name.
```

Comment: Great! Np. Please accept the answer when you get a chance so other people know it worked. Thank you!